# A way to check if "(current-kill 0)" will run onto an error before it happens

Tags: error-handling, kill-ring, conditionals

I have an Elisp part involving `(current-kill 0)` to copy the current clipboard content into a variable.  This works flawlessly as long as the kill-ring has content.  However, if I just started the computer and did not copy anything yet (or use the command-line version of Emacs), running that script runs into the error "Kill ring is empty".

Trying `(cond (kill-ring) my_code)` seems dodgy since when starting Emacs and before `(current-kill 0)` is executed, `kill-ring` is actually nil as per <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> `kill-ring`.

Is there a reliable way to find out if the clipboard actually holds content without getting the code running onto an error?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Are you asking how to check whether the `kill-ring` is empty (just test whether `kill-ring` is non-`nil`), or are you asking how to avoid the error that it's empty? If the latter, just put something in it, to start with (using `kill-new` - e.g. `(kill-new "DUMMY")`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking *how to check* whether the `kill-ring` is empty? If so, just test whether `kill-ring` is non-`nil`:

```lisp
(when kill-ring ...)
```

Or are you asking how to avoid the error that it's empty? If so, just put something in it, to start with, using `kill-new`. For example:

```lisp
(kill-new "DUMMY")
```

You can also use `ignore-errors` to just ignore that error or all errors:

```lisp
(ignore-errors
  ;; Code that expects a non-empty `kill-ring`
  )
```

Comment: I am indeed asking on how to avoid the error happening (or, if even better check the content of `(current-kill 0)` without errors).  Bluntly placing a new entry would likely replace (as in move) a potentially valid entry from position 0 (zero).  I will check if `(ignore-errors)` does what I expect.  Thanks!  Will be back shortly.

Comment: The `(ignore-errors)` command is precisely what I needed.  Thanks!